# Java - repeatedly run a function in a given number of milliseconds accurately?

Tags: java, time

Does anyone have a Fairly effective way of running a function repetitively in a precise and accurate number of milliseconds. I have tried to accomplish this by using the code below to try to run a function called wave() once a second for 30 seconds:

```
startTime = System.nanoTime();
        wholeTime = System.nanoTime();
        while (loop) {
            if (startTime >= time2) {
                startTime = System.nanoTime();
                wave();
                sec++;
            }
            if (sec == 30) {
                loop = false;
                endTime = System.nanoTime();
                System.out.println(wholeTime - System.nanoTime());
            }
        }

    }
```

This code did not work and am wondering why this code didn't work and if their is a better approach to the problem. Any ideas on how to improve fix the above code or other successful ways of accomplishing the problem are all welcome. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The system clock is almost certainly no more precise than `System.currentTimeMillis()` at ~15ms granularity.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here. `time2` is never defined and `endTime` is never used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

more simple:

```
long start=System.currentTimeMillis(); // Not very very accurate

while (System.currentTimeMillis()-start<30000)
{
wave();
// count something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Timer+TimerTask: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html
http://bioportal.weizmann.ac.il/course/prog2/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Thread.sleep()`:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    int count = 30;
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        wave();
        // how many milliseconds till the end of the second?
        long sleep = start+(i+1)*1000-System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(sleep > 0) // condition might be false if wave() runs longer than second
            Thread.sleep(sleep);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> Does anyone have a Fairly effective way of running a function repetitively in a precise and accurate number of milliseconds.

There is no way to do this kind of thing **reliably and accurately** in standard Java.  The problem is that there is no way that you can guarantee that your thread will run when you want ti to run.  For example:

- your thread could be suspended to allow the GC to run
- your thread could be preempted to allow another thread in your application to run
- your thread could be suspended by the OS while it fetches pages by the JVM back from disk.

You can only get reliable behavior for this kind of code if you run on a hard realtime OS, and an realtime Java.

Note that this is not an issue with clock accuracy.  The real problem is that the scheduler does not give you the kind of guarantees you need.  For instance, none of the "sleep until X" functionality in a JVM can guarantee that your thread will wake up at time X exactly ... for *any* useful meaning of "exactly".

The other answers suggest various ways to do this, but beware that they are not (and cannot be) reliable and accurate in all circumstances .. or even on a typical machine running other things as well as your application.